# MySQL Constraint not working - error code #1452

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

For the whole day I've been struggling to get this contstraint going.

The code for the tables involved is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GEBRUIKER` 
(
`GEBRUIKERSNR` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`VOORNAAM` text,
`TUSSENVOEGSEL` text,
`ACHTERNAAM` text NOT NULL,
`GESLACHT` BOOLEAN,
`WACHTWOORD` text NOT NULL,
`GEB_DATUM` DATE,
`E-MAIL` text NOT NULL,
`TELEFOON` INT(10),
`STRAAT` text,
`HUISNUMMER` INT(3),
`POSTCODE` text,
`WOONPLAATS` text,      

PRIMARY KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `GEBRUIKERS`
--

INSERT INTO `GEBRUIKER` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`, `VOORNAAM`, `TUSSENVOEGSEL`, `ACHTERNAAM`,     `GESLACHT`, `WACHTWOORD`, `GEB_DATUM`, `E-MAIL`, `TELEFOON`, `STRAAT`, `HUISNUMMER`, `POSTCODE`, `WOONPLAATS`) VALUES

(99999, 'An', NULL, 'Oniem', 'm', 'anoniem', 1991-12-13, 'anoniem@anoniem.net', '0612345678', 'anoniemstraat', '01', '0001 AN', 'Anoniemville');
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AFSPRAAK`
(
`DATENUMMER` int(10) NOT NULL,
`GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`ACCEPTATIE` BOOLEAN,
`BERICHT` text,
`TIJDSTIP` DATE,
`LOCATIE` text,

PRIMARY KEY (`DATENUMMER`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `AFSPRAAK`
--

INSERT INTO `AFSPRAAK` (`DATENUMMER`, `GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN`, `GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR`, `ACCEPTATIE`, `BERICHT`, `TIJDSTIP`, `LOCATIE`) VALUES

('9999999999', '99999', '99999', TRUE, 'Hey, wanna go out? :)', '2014-02-27 11:04:00', 'Cafe de Bezige Bij, Hofstraat 5, Rotterdam');
```

The code for the constrain I made is:

```
ALTER TABLE `AFSPRAAK`
ADD CONSTRAINT `afspraak_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN`) REFERENCES `GEBRUIKER` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `afspraak_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR`) REFERENCES `GEBRUIKER` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

From PHPMyAdmin I'm getting this:

```
ERROR    
SQL-query:

ALTER TABLE  `AFSPRAAK` ADD CONSTRAINT  `afspraak_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (  `GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN` ) REFERENCES  `GEBRUIKER` (  `GEBRUIKERSNR` ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ,
ADD CONSTRAINT  `afspraak_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (  `GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR` ) REFERENCES  `GEBRUIKER` (  `GEBRUIKERSNR` ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;


MySQL reports: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dateos`.`#sql-1684_68`, CONSTRAINT `afspraak_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN`) REFERENCES `gebruiker` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

What do I do now? Also, why isn't this working?

Comment: [Your `insert`s doesn't seem to be correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea823)

Comment: look at the sqlfiddle - it yells, that you cannot insert char into boolean

Comment: I changed "Boolean" to a tinyint(1), with the value of the tinyint being 'Ý'. I still have the same error code.

Comment: How stupid of me, filling in a letter where there's supposed to be a digit. However, still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `INDEX`es on the foreign **`KEY`** columns:

```
INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN),
INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR)
```

and your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint [shall be created](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a62):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GEBRUIKER` 
(
  `GEBRUIKERSNR` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `VOORNAAM` text,
  `TUSSENVOEGSEL` text,
  `ACHTERNAAM` text NOT NULL,
  `GESLACHT` BOOLEAN,
  `WACHTWOORD` text NOT NULL,
  `GEB_DATUM` DATE,
  `E-MAIL` text NOT NULL,
  `TELEFOON` INT(10),
  `STRAAT` text,
  `HUISNUMMER` INT(3),
  `POSTCODE` text,
  `WOONPLAATS` text,

  PRIMARY KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AFSPRAAK`
(
  `DATENUMMER` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `ACCEPTATIE` BOOLEAN,
  `BERICHT` text,
  `TIJDSTIP` DATE,
  `LOCATIE` text,

  PRIMARY KEY (`DATENUMMER`),
  INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN),
  INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `AFSPRAAK`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `afspraak_ibfk_2` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN`) 
    REFERENCES `GEBRUIKER` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `afspraak_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR`) 
    REFERENCES `GEBRUIKER` (`GEBRUIKERSNR`) 
      ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: This unforunately causes another error:
`"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_VAN),
    INDEX (GEBRUIKERSNR_NAAR)
        
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT ' at line 18 "`

Comment: @Quinten05 Did you put the `,` here -> `PRIMARY KEY (DATENUMMER),`?